# Запуск async функции без awiat ожидание результата JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, promise, ecmascript

Разъясните ситуацию:

```
export const app = express();

//VAR 1
app.post('/path', async function (request, response) {
  ...
  asyncFunction();
});    

//VAR 2
app.post('/path', async function (request, response) {
  ...
  await asyncFunction();
});
```

Будет какое то отличие между этими двумя вариантами?

В первом варианте `tslint` ругается что промис не обработан, и в случае ошибки выбросит в консоль `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

Во втором нормально.

Но допустим `asyncFunction` посылает данные на другой сервер, и мне все равно что он на это ответит. Тогда в первом варианте программа может освободить все используемые ресурсы и не ждать ответа, а во втором она ждет ответ (который мне не нужен) и при этом не позволят завершиться `async function (request, response)` со всеми ресурсам что она выделила.

Это так?

Будет ли тогда `asyncFunction().catch()` решением всех проблем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если оператор `await` не присутствует в асинхронной функции (async) то она будет выполнена как обычная, т.е синхронно.

```
// запись с async без await 
app.post("/path", async function (request, response) {
  asyncFunction()
})

// то же самое что
app.post("/path", function (request, response) {
  asyncFunction()
})
```

```js
console.log(1)

async function test () {
  console.log(2)
}

test()

console.log(3)
// 1
// 2
// 3
```

Comment: вместо игнора сделал return. А что на счет " программа может освободить все используемые ресурсы и не ждать ответа" Ну то есть будет ли await в конце функции потреблять больше времени/ресурсов программы?

Comment: @ValeraKvip Если функция не завершена (ждем await), то функция существует в памяти. Как только ответ будет получен мы двинемся к следующей строчке внутри этой асинхронной функции (т.е блокирующее поведение внутри функции)